# How to add together values in an array using a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, assignment-operator

The aim of this method is to find the average speed during a bike ride. I already have a method `speeds()` which returns the average values between GPS points stored in a double array. I tried to use a for loop and an add-and assignment to add together the values and store them in a double variable `totalOfSpeeds`. For some reason, the values don't add up, but rather the value of `totalOfSpeeds` changes for each "round" of the for loop, as if i used a normal `=` assignment. Any help would be appreciated.

```
double averageSpeed() {

double average = 0;

double [] avgSpeedsCopy = Arrays.copyOf(speeds(), speeds().length);

double totalOfSpeeds  = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < speeds().length; i++) {

    totalOfSpeeds =+ avgSpeedsCopy[i];


}

average = totalOfSpeeds/speeds().length;

return average;
}
```

Comment: It's `+=`, not `=+`

Answer (score 2):

Your for-loop solution looks good once you fix the typo QBrute pointed out. You can also one line this using streams.

```
DoubleStream.of(arr).average().getAsDouble()
```